# Issue when installing utility module

Tags: python, pip

I try to install python utility:

```
pip install utility
```

but the module is not found after installation.

I tried unsuccessfully to set up permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Then I realized after uninstall /install utility that pip shows a warning during the installation:

```
 WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
```

I guess that could be my issue. How can I get through that?

**EDIT**

The comments and answer was helpful to solve the issue. I was trying to import the "utility" file from this [audio toolbox](https://github.com/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/utility.py) while there is an other python module named "utility" which does not contain any function.

Comment: I wonder whether in `setup.py` the line `packages=['']`, should be `packages=[],`

Comment: It doesn't look as though [the **`setup.py`**](https://bitbucket.org/tmthyjames/utilitybelt/src/c0a9dc8acd7f4a55a10abb6fd9ef2630d171b3ea/setup.py?fileviewer=file-view-default) actually installs anything /c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Wood noted in the comments, it looks like that package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utility/1.0) isn't actually set up to install anything.  I'm not sure what you wanted to use it for, but as far as I can tell, the utility package is really just a single python file which you could just download from https://bitbucket.org/tmthyjames/utilitybelt/raw/c0a9dc8acd7f4a55a10abb6fd9ef2630d171b3ea/utilitybelt.py (if that link doesn't work, https://bitbucket.org/tmthyjames/utilitybelt.git , click source, and then click raw)

Comment: where do i put these files ?